# Linux Mint + Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, gradle, postman, linux-mint, android-instant-run

I had got my system formatted. I have linux mint installed on laptop with 8gb ram and Intel i5 processor.

I have installed Android studio 2.1 stable version and have configured it for instant run. First it was running very well for few days but now my laptop is hanging frequently and I have to restart it in every while.

I had increased heap size to 15000mb in gradle.properties within .gradle folder for instant run to work properly.

I had installed jdk 1.8, android studio, chrome and postman setup in 
system.

Any help to fix issue would be appreciated

Comment: That's good. You run into a whole number of problems when you use 32 bits. (Like with ADB.)

Comment: But i am facing issues with 64 bit. Do you have a solution?

Comment: I had tried command: "free -m". This command tells how much RAM is used and how much RAM is free. I found that while using instant Run feature, almost full ram was been utilized and my system was not getting enough left RAM due to which it was  hanging and I had to restart system every while.  I had disabled Instant Run option in studio and now my studio + system is working fine. Build now taking around 3 minutes which is not bad rather than restarting system every time. Hope this helps :)

Comment: It will help everyone if you post that as the answer. :)